# Why do other applications open, when I open a certain script on applescript?

Tags: applescript

Every time i open this specific script, other applications open with it and i haven't even clicked on run. Applications like Appstore and system information open, and they are only mentioned in the script once, halfway through:

```
tell application "Grab" to quit
tell application "Network Utility" to quit
tell application "System Information" to quit
tell application "Terminal" to quit
tell application "Keychain Access" to quit
tell application "Disk Utility" to quit
tell application "Bluetooth File Exchange" to quit
tell application "Boot Camp Assistant" to quit
tell application "AirPort Utility" to quit
tell application "Activity Monitor" to quit
tell application "App Store" to quit
tell application "iTunes" to quit
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open the script in script editor, it will open all necessary apps in order to load their library terminology. It has always operated this way. It's especially annoying when you open someone's script that has tell blocks to apps that you don't have installed.

Comment: I do think it odd that it does this behavior when opening a script, but not when you "Compile" a script.

Comment: yea true, but luckily it doesn't otherwise that would be really annoying, as i compile every time i enter a command

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question because you already have the answer.

But, here's how to not open these applications when you want to edit the script.
Just put the application name in a variable.

```
set appNames to {"Grab", "Network Utility", "System Information", "Terminal", "Keychain Access", "Disk Utility", "Bluetooth File Exchange", "Boot Camp Assistant", "AirPort Utility", "Activity Monitor", "App Store", "iTunes"}
repeat with tName in appNames
    quit application tName
end repeat
```

Answer (score -1):

An AppleScript can’t tell an app to do something if that app is not running. So if a script includes a “tell” statement that targets a specific app, that app has to run along with the script. It’s the same as invoking a PHP library function in a PHP script. If you use a strpos function in a PHP script, then that PHP script can’t run without strpos also running.

This is by design because the purpose of AppleScript is to create workflows that include multiple apps working in concert on a specific task. AppleScript itself has almost no built-in functionality — your AppleScripts get their functionality from Mac apps, Unix apps, and network services.

In the script you’re working with, you can comment-out those lines (put two dashes in front of each line) if you know that those apps will not be running, because all it is doing there is telling those apps to Quit. That AppleScript is not using those apps for any real functionality.

Comment: thanks for the detailed description of why it opens. Although before that part of the script, they were opened, i just didn't want to post the whole script since it was too long. 

I'm a newB on applescript still :P so when you say to comment-out the line (e.g. --tell application "ITunes" to quit), wouldn't it be better just to leave it out then relating to other commands as well, since it doesn't have any "function".

Comment: note that the op was asking why the apps open when you open the script. your description is really about runtime. You can enter tell blocks, compile and move on while editing, and the apps don't open until runtime.